# Matplotlib on Jupyter malfunctioning

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Whenever I re-run a jupyter notebook from someone else my plots look lower quality. I don't change any code but they don't look the same.

I have tried using different versions of matplotlib; installing and uninstalling anaconda; changing my browser (i usually use chrome); using both python 2.7 and 3.5 but whenever I rerun a code the plots don't look the same as you can see below.

This problem doesn't affect any of my friends. I can't export these plots to any ppt or text file because of low quality.

Does anyone else having the same problem?

Before[image: without rerunning the code]

After[image: after rerunning the code]

Before[image]

After[image]

Comment: What exactly does "before" and "after" mean here? Before or after *what*? I do not observe any difference in quality. Just the design is different. Please state *exactly*  what you would like to change about your plots.

Comment: Notebooks are usually saved with code executed. So whenever I open someone's notebook I can see the tables and plots they created. Whenever I rerun their code for the plot, the design of the plot looks different. All histograms and scatterplots on matplotlib should by default look like the ones in the before images. However, my plots don't even show the default designs for each plot type

Comment: All plots are produced with the default design. However the default design of your matplotlib version is different than the one from your friends; you have a newer version than they have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is no objective change in quality. The different style can only be subjectively better or worse.

The plots called "after" in the question are produced by matplotlib version 2 or higher, while the plots called "before" are produced by matplotlib version 1.5 or lower.

All style changes between the two versions are documented in the [Changes to the default style](http://matplotlib.org/2.0.0rc2/users/dflt_style_changes.html) article.

Most changes can be reverted in matplotlib 2.0 using the command

```
plt.style.use('classic')
```

Comment: I would say there is an objective change. The outline of each data point has changed, as well as the color.

Comment: "change in quality". Who would be able to objectively judge on whether a point with an outline has higher quality than one without?

Comment: I'm not saying it is better or worse, just that it has changed.

Comment: Same as I am saying. Did you downvote the answer for telling the truth?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest you were right. Changing the style to classic make the plots look like in the before picture. Thanks

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes, I downvoted your post because I misunderstood it. I've corrected it.